# Can Android play an array of ints as audio without converting to .wav or similar?

Tags: android, audio, midi, wave, trigonometry

I simply want to create a sine wave and have my app play it. Is there a simple way to do this, rather than creating and saving a whole new file for the AudioManager to read? Can it read it directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [AudioTrack](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html) class, specifically the `write()` methods. There are several there to choose from, but the one that takes in a `float[]` array of data is probably the easiest way to play a generated sine wave from your app.